# Check for Anagram in 2 strings

Tags: javascript

I've created a function that checks if 2 words are anagrams, but I want to make it better. I feel the declaration of the counter after in the if statement is not quite well, if anybody have a better solution would be great.

```
function checkAnagram(string1, string2){

        if(string1.length !== string2.length){
            return false;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < string1.length; i++){

            if(count <= 0){

                return false;
            }
            var count = 0;

            for(var t = 0; t < string2.length; t++){

                //counter = 0

                if(string2[t].toLowerCase() == string1[i].toLowerCase()){
                    //counter++;
                    count++;
                    break;
                }


            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Just a side note: return false for `string1 === string2`. After all, "apples" is not an anagram of "apples".

Comment: An anagram is a word made with the same letters, in a different order. That being said, to check for an anagram, the only think you have to do is create an array of letters for each word, sort the array and compare them. The function you want is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23785653/5768908

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a much easier way of doing it:

```
var s1 = "test"
var s2 = "tset"

function testAnagram (s1, s2){

 if(!s1 || !s2 || s1.length !== s2.length){return false;}

 var lS1 = s1.toLowerCase();
 var lS2 = s2.toLowerCase();

 if(lS1 === lS2) {return false;}

 var rS1 = lS1.split('').sort().join('');
 var rS2 = lS2.split('').sort().join('');

 return rS1 === rS2;
}



var result = testAnagram(s1, s2);

alert(result);
```

Comment: change s2 to "ttse" and you get a "false".

Comment: ??? I think you want `.sort()` and not `.reverse()`, and you have to sort *both* strings. An *anagram* is a word formed from the arbitrary rearrangement of letters in another word.

Comment: oops I misunderstood the question one sec

Comment: ok that should be correct now.  I was thinking of a palindrome.

Comment: You should convert the strings to lowercase before sorting in case the words use mixed case, because it will sort them differently.

Comment: Now it's good! But just as I wrote in the question, a function to check an anagram should return false for `str1 === str2`, because "computer" is not an anagram of "computer".

Comment: you can also check if the lengths are equal as in the original solution, because it doesn't make sense to check if they're not

Answer (score 8):

Your code returns true for strings 'aabb' and 'abcc', which are not anagrams. You can just sort the strings and check if they're equal:

```
function checkAnagram(string1, string2) {
   return string1.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("") === string2.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkAnagram(string1, string2) {
   return string1.replace(/[^\w]/g,'').toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('') === 
        string2.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w]/g,'').split('').sort().join('')
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain your code as well.

Comment: converting strings to lower case and making sure that spaces are eliminated using regex and sort them and compare them

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't want to use prebuild methods like .split() .sort() .join() then**

```js
function isAnagrams(stringA, stringB) {
      // just to remove special char and convert it to lowercase
      stringA = stringA.replace(/[^\w]/g, "").toLowerCase();
      stringB = stringB.replace(/[^\w]/g, "").toLowerCase();
      if (stringA.length !== stringB.length) return false;
      let aCharMap = {};
      let bCharMap = {};
      /* 
        making of mapObject of both string, containing character as property and 
        count of that character as value 
      */
      for (let i = 0; i < stringA.length; i++) {
        bCharMap[stringB[i]] = bCharMap[stringB[i]] + 1 || 1;
        aCharMap[stringA[i]] = aCharMap[stringA[i]] + 1 || 1;
      }
      //  checking both CharMap value
      for (let q of stringB) {
        if (bCharMap[q] !== aCharMap[q]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
}  

console.log(`isAnagram : ${isAnagrams('rail safety', 'fairy tales')}`)
```

so if you pass `isAnagrams('rail safety','fairy tales');` then character map will look like this

```
aCharMap = { r: 1, a: 2, i: 1, l: 1, s: 1, f: 1, e: 1, t: 1, y: 1 }
bCharMap = { f: 1, a: 2, i: 1, r: 1, y: 1, t: 1, l: 1, e: 1, s: 1 }
```

then we will compare if they have same value or not based on that result will be decided

Answer (score 0):

```
function isAnagram(str1, str2){
    if(str1.length !== str2.length){
        return false
    }

    let string1 = str1.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');
    let string2 = str2.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');
    return string1 === string2
}
isAnagram('abcdef', 'AbcFed')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit different approach:

```
function isAnagram(one, two) {
  const copyOne = one.split('');
  const copyTwo = two.split('');
  if (copyOne.length === copyTwo.length) {
    for (let i=0; i<=copyOne.length; i++) {
      const letterAt = copyTwo.indexOf(copyOne[i]);
      if (letterAt > -1) copyTwo.splice(letterAt, 1);
    }
    if (copyTwo.length === 0) return true;
    else return false;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(isAnagram((one = "anagram"), (two = "nagaram")));
```