# Check it two strings are anagrams of each other

Tags: javascript

```
isAnagram(firstString, secondString)
```

Parameters

```
firstString - any JavaScript String
secondString - any JavaScript String
Return Value
```

A Boolean indicating whether or not secondString is an anagram of firstString.

Examples

```
isAnagram('restful', 'fluster')             // -> true
isAnagram('dormitory', 'dirty room')        // -> true
isAnagram('roses', 'horse')                 // -> false
isAnagram('debit card', 'bad credit')       // -> true
isAnagram('nearby there', 'nearly three')   // -> false
isAnagram('school master', 'the classroom') // -> true
isAnagram('ludicrous', 'ridiculous')        // -> false
isAnagram('anagram', 'nag a ram')           // -> true
```

so far i have

```
function isAnagram(firstString, secondString) {
  return firstString.replace(' ','').split('').sort().join('') === secondString.replace(' ','').split('').sort().join('')
}
```

but im getting an error AssertionError: expected false to equal true

for the last one 'nag a ram'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check for Anagram in 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942748/check-for-anagram-in-2-strings)

Comment: @Ekrem I think you're thinking of palindromes.

Comment: If my answer addresses your needs thoroughly and passes all the test cases, you may mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If your criteria for 2 strings to be the anagram of each other is exact same quantity of each alphabetic character for both strings, caseinsensitively, you may go something, like that:

```js
const testCases = [['restful', 'fluster', true],['dormitory', 'dirty room', true],['roses', 'horse', false],['debit card', 'bad credit', true],['nearby there', 'nearly three', false],['school master', 'the classroom', true],['ludicrous', 'ridiculous', false],['anagram', 'nag a ram', true]],

      isAnagram = (s1,s2) => {
        const countLetters = s =>
              [...s].reduce((r,c) => {
                const key = c.toLowerCase()
                if(/[a-z]/i.test(c)) 
                  r[key] = (r[key]||0)+1
                return r
              },{}),
              countS1 = countLetters(s1),
              countS2 = countLetters(s2)
        return  Object.keys(countS1).length == Object.keys(countS2).length &&
                Object
                  .keys(countS1)
                  .every(c => countS2[c] == countS1[c])
      }
      
console.log(testCases.every(([s1,s2,res]) => isAnagram(s1,s2) == res))
```

Comment: isAnagram("abbc","abcc") // true

Comment: This is cool, but the OP has asked for `isAnagram('dormitory', 'dirty room')` to be `true`.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery , evolutionxbox : do you like it better now, guys?